# How to insert coma separated strings in mapped column in database table using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, csv

Here is my data in input tag separated by coma.

> CODE002,WHITE,TATA,IT-00-0728,6

Now i want to pass this data into column in database.

DB table name = item_data

Table structure:

> [image: Blockquote]

now i want data to be inserted in the following way

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Please include your current code you are using for the insert.

Comment: Perfect reason to use a Parameterised Prepared and bound query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to retrieve data from the string

```
$data = explode(",", $string);
```

Then [insert it to the database](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id7)

```
$insert = array(
   "item_code" => $data[1],
   "color" => $data[2],
    :
    :
);

$this->db->insert("item_data", $insert);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day its perfectly working.